# c++ How to make sure that my function execute completly before getting killed

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, function

I have a C++ function running on a single thread.

For example;

```
function()
{
 Line 1; commit(ms sql) 
 Line 2; commit(oracle)
}
```

This function needs to complete fully.

I want to know if, in the event someone kills the process from task manager, there is a way to prevent the application from breaking in between line 1 and line 2.

If 1 executes then 2 has to do so as well.

Is this possible and if so, what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Imagine if this were possible. Somebody might decide that line 2 is `Sleep(INFINITE)`. Now you have an unkillable process.

Comment: It certainly is operating system specific. The C++ latest standards (e.g. C++11) don't know about *processes* (but C++11 has threads).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this.  If the kernel decides your process should die, your process dies.

Comment: For completeness, you can catch some signals, but if you want to kill the process, there is nothing to prevent it.

Comment: If this is the case, how to prevent the bug when I transact between two databases?

Comment: If it is not complete, it should get rolled back on both DB.  IF you're migrating data, you must code it so that your compound transaction gets rolled back on both DB if not committed on both.

Answer (score 0):

if Line 1 and 2 are modify some data structure.

may be, you need some form of transaction mechanism.

you can, for example :

1. include Line 1 and 2 in one database transaction.
2. make Line 1 and 2 modify some temporary data struct ,
   and use a atomic instruction like cas to commit temporary 
   data to final data struct.